# UIWebview tripadvisor redirection bug to their app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, http-redirect

Recently I just discovered a little issue.
I'm using UIWebview to load some url some times nothing really fancy, just basic init:

```
self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, navBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-navBar.frame.size.height)];
    self.webview.opaque = NO;
    self.webview.delegate = self;
    self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webview];
```

and i'm loading the url like this:

```
if(self.webview)
    {
        [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    }
```

The problem that i got is when i try to redirect to tripadvisor mobile page I got a pop up saying that my version is not handled anymore and that i need to update it, the thing is that even with the last update it doesnt work...

And it's the same for ios6, 7 and 8 and only for IPHONE ...

Is there anybody who got the same problem ? and maybe fixed it ?

Thanks !
Here is the image of the popup:
[image: error popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved by change `UIWebView`'s user-agent

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Safari iOS 8.0 - iPhone", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

put it before your webview initialize.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah i think it's the only way to fix it, but it needs an update. But thanks !